# Error retrieving data from hive using python

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop, hive, pyhive

I use python to connect hive & retrieve the data into pandas, but its giving an error:

```
pyhive.exc.OperationalError: TExecuteStatementResp
```

my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pyhive import hive
from impala.util import as_pandas
from string import Template

config = {
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'database': 'default'
}

def get_conn(conf):
    conn = hive.connect(**conf)
    return conn

def execute_hql(hql, params = None):
    conn = get_conn(config)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    hql = Template(hql).substitute(params)
    cursor.execute(hql)
    df = as_pandas(cursor)
    return df
```

test.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pyhive import hive
from impala.util import as_pandas
import DB.hive_engines

hql = """
    SELECT
        keywords,
        count(keywords)
    FROM
        table
    WHERE
        eventname = 'xxx' AND
        cdate >= '$start_date' AND
        cdate <= '$end_date'
    GROUP BY
        keywords
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = {'start_date': '2016-04-01', 'end_date': '2016-04-03'}
    df = DB.hive_engines.execute_hql(hql, params)
    print df
```

exception message:

> pyhive.exc.OperationalError: TExecuteStatementResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=1, errorMessage='Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask', sqlState='08S01', infoMessages=['*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask:28:27', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:326', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runQuery:SQLOperation.java:146', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runInternal:SQLOperation.java:173', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:run:Operation.java:268', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementInternal:HiveSessionImpl.java:410', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatement:HiveSessionImpl.java:391', 'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31:invoke::-1', 'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43', 'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:606', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:78', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:36', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:63', 'java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2', 'javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:415', 'org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1671', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:59', 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27:executeStatement::-1', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:executeStatement:CLIService.java:245', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:ExecuteStatement:ThriftCLIService.java:509', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1313', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1298', 'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39', 'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39', 'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56', 'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:285', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615', 'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745'], statusCode=3), operationHandle=None)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/101653/pyhive-interface-does-not-seem-to-work-for-more-di.html) discussion, I used a valid username while creating the connection and that solved the problem.

For the sake of completeness of this answer, I am copy pasting the suggested code from the above mentioned forum. Please note the valid username there.

```
from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host='<myhost>',
            port='<myport>',
            database='spin1',
            username='<a valid user>')  # IMPORTANT**
cursor = conn.cursor()
print cursor.fetchall()
```

In absence of the valid username, I was hitting the same exception mentioned in the question.